# How to set dynamic return type for rest template

Tags: java, rest, object, reflection

I just want to set the dynamic return type of the object returned by `postForObject`. This is what I have tried, but its not working.Herein `DecryptedData` is the return type but I am changing it to `Object`.

```
Object[] decryptedDataArray = restTemplate.postForObject(url, dataToBeDecryptedList.toArray(), Object[].class);

if(decryptedDataArray instanceof DecryptedData[]){
    if (decryptedDataArray != null && decryptedDataArray.length > 0) {
        fieldDataMap = setDecryptedData(fieldDataMap, (DecryptedData[]) decryptedDataArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would the `RestTemplate` return a `DecryptedData[]` in your example?

Comment: Yes because the it is destined to return `DecryptedData`.But suppose I don't know what object it is to return.How would I handle this then?

Comment: Explain why you think it is destined to return `DecryptedData`. What does `RestTemplate` know about `DecryptedData`?

Comment: This will post the data to the required client.The client will render and send `DecryptedData` as the response.But what if I dont know what the client reponse be?

Comment: No. It won't send `DecryptedData`. It will send some **bytes**,  that are to be interpreted as JSON text. If you don't tell `RestTemplate` to further interpret that JSON text as a Java `DecryptedData[]` object, it cannot guess it on its own.

Comment: Ok so we are the consumer of the service so we cant do anything as such.the thing is we want to cast the response as per the status code.